# Equivalent français de « the former … the latter »

Tags: anglais, pronoms, énumération

Quel serait le meilleur équivalent de la construction anglaise *the former … the latter* ?

(je ne cherche pas le sens de l'expression, mais une expression/construction français équivalente)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Le premier*, *le second*. À accorder en genre et en nombre avec l'objet auquel ils se rapportent.

> … les pouvoirs publics, les corps intermédiaires, les groupes de pression d'un côté, et l'opinion publique de l'autre, les premiers s'efforçant de dévoiler et parfois de manipuler la seconde.   ([*La Seconde révolution contraceptive : la régulation des naissances en France de 1950 à 1985*, Introduction par H. Leridon](http://books.google.fr/books?id=S-1bNENVJMMC&pg=PA4&dq=%22les+premiers%22+%22la+seconde%22))

(On peut aussi utiliser *premier* et *deuxième*, mais certains pédants insistent pour utiliser *second* pour une énumération à deux éléments et *deuxième* quand il y a plus de deux éléments.)

Comment: _Le dernier_, parfois _ce dernier_ est aussi possible.

Comment: @Unfrancophone *Le dernier*, dans une énumération avec seulement deux éléments, ça me paraît bizarre, ça me fait chercher un élément au milieu.

Comment: Il ne me semble pas que ce soit limité à ces cas.  Ça me semble même courant quand _le premier_ est donné en dernier (dans une structure en chiasme) ou n'est pas donné du tout.

Comment: *Le dernier* peut-être pas, mais en tout cas *ce dernier* s'utilise couramment même s'il n'y a qu'un élément, donc pas de problème pour deux.

Answer (score 3):

Je crois que l‘on peut aussi ajouter « -là » ou « -ci » après le bon pronom démonstratif (celui/celle/celles/ceux) pour dire « former » et « latter », le premier (« -là ») pour dire « former »/« former cases » et le second (« -ci ») pour dire « latter »/« latter cases».

Answer (score 3):

Les Uns et les Autres peuvent aussi utiliser pour Latter et Former.
J'ai trouvé ces lignes dans "Les Misérables" qui ont "les uns" utilisé comme "latter" et "les autres" utilisé comme "Former". Voir ci-dessous:

"Au bout de peu de temps, les offrandes
d’argent affluèrent. Ceux qui ont et ceux qui
manquent frappaient à la porte de M. Myriel, **les
uns** venant chercher l’aumône que **les autres**
venaient y déposer."

J'ai trouvé la traduction de cela comme ça

"After a time, offerings of money flowed in. Those who had and those who lacked knocked at M. Myriel's door,--**the latter** in search of the alms which **the former** came to deposit."
Link of the translation: http://www.online-literature.com/victor_hugo/les_miserables/2/